# How to get the records of one table,in which the fields exist in another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table A(serv_id,cust_id,acct_id), table B(serv_id,charge).
The total records of A is about 100,000 and the total records of B is about20,000.

Now I want to get the record of A where the serv_in exist in table B. I try the join method to get the results. But it's too slow. So I want to know is there any other way to solute this with Procedure or other method?

This is what OP tried

```
select a.* from A a , B b where a.serv_id = b.serv_id(+)
```

Comment: Post what you tried...

Comment: what version of oracle, are there primary keys and indexes,what hardware is it on, what is your query, how slow is too slow

Comment: select a.* from A a , B b where a.serv_id = b.serv_id(+)

Answer (score 0):

You said *Now I want to get the record of A where the serv_in exist in table B. I try the join method to get the results.*

`select a.* from A a , B b where a.serv_id = b.serv_id` should work and I just removed the outer join from your statement. Try this and if you face a slowdown, revert with more details.